# Docker containers with multiple log sources

Tags: docker

Say I have a container that has everything I need to run my web application (such as https://github.com/grigio/docker-stringer for example). How would I go about inspecting the logs for the different services (web server, application server, database server)? With all of the tutorials so far I have only been able to view the logs for the specific command run when starting the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to configure your logs to write to `stdout` and to use `docker logs` to retrieve them.

Another option would be to use a `bindmount` and link to your host file system.

Comment: I can see using stdout if there was only one source of logs that I was interested, but if more than one service is running in the container that approach won't work. I see some discussion of VOLUMES on the docker wiki https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/wiki/Volumes-&-persistent-data-storage which I think is similar to your bindmount suggestion and word work well in my opinion.

Comment: Yes. Volumes allow data to be shared across containers. Bindmounts allow you to tell the host/container to share the same directory. `docker run -v ./logs:/logs image` would mount the local (host) ./logs directory accessible by the container in /logs.

Comment: Great! This looks exactly like what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You'd have an example or a link to some, for your first method, the one about configuring the logs to write to `stdout` ?

Comment: @NickStinemates how do you go about permissions to the mounted volume? When I did what you suggest, the mounted `/logs` folder inside the container is created with the owner and group `root`, while my application in the container runs with the user `daemon`. Consequently, my app cannot write to the `/logs` folder. Any ideas?

Comment: In case anybody has the same issue as myself, I just found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29251160/1972469). Basically you need to set the user and group id (uid:gid) on the host folder the same as the uid:gid of the user running the application in docker.