# Docker volume - need permissions to write to database

Tags: python, sqlite, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm working on a flask server (in a virtualenv with python 3.5) which is used as a REST API (only for development as suggested for flask). In the beginning it connects to a local sqlite database and it will commit any db changes as soon as possible. Now I wanted to run everything in a docker container and I was wondering how I can access the database because the sqlite file is located in the container.

So I created a volume in a docker-compose file which points to the dockerfile building the application.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
ENV HOME /home/parkrep
WORKDIR $HOME
ADD requirements.txt $HOME/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . $HOME
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

.dockerignore

```
__pycache__
venv
.gitignore
.dockerignore
README.md
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  parkrep:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./output:/home/parkrep/output
    command: ["python", "server.py"]
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

If I run `docker-compose up` I get the following

```
parkrep_1  |   File "/home/parkrep/db_connector.py", line 45, in _connect_db
parkrep_1  |     self._connection = sqlite3.connect(path, check_same_thread=False)
parkrep_1  | sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
parkrep_parkrep_1 exited with code 1
```

If I create the database at output/reports.db and start docker-compose again, it returns the following error:

```
parkrep_1  | sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

So obviously I don't have permissions to write to the file. I tested this behavior by writing to a test file which is mounted like this:

```
...
volumes:
  - ./output:/home/parkrep/output
  - ./test.txt:/home/parkrep/text.txt
command: bash -c "echo 'hallo' > test.txt"
```

Error message:

```
parkrep_1  | bash: text.txt: Permission denied
```

Let's see who owns this file:

```
parkrep_1  | drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Dec 19 10:45 .
parkrep_1  | -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  143 Dec 12 15:08 config.yaml
parkrep_1  | -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 7.9K Dec 12 14:37 db_connector.py
parkrep_1  | drwxrwxr-x 2 4262 4262 4.0K Dec 19 11:10 output
parkrep_1  | -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  144 Dec 12 13:20 requirements.txt
parkrep_1  | -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2.7K Dec 19 10:14 server.py
parkrep_1  | -rw-rw-r-- 1 4262 4262 2.7K Dec 19 10:14 test.txt
```

It turns out that there is no user 4262 in the container but on the host machine my user account has this id. So I think I know what the problem is now, but I have no clue how to get access to these files. I tried adding ":rw" to the volume definitions but I still don't have write permissions. How can I tell docker to not change the file/directory owner if a volume is defined.

I'm thinking of a problem with my local volume driver, but maybe someone else already had this problem and can tell me how to configure my image to get the required permissions.

Greetings,
Thomas

`docker info`

```
     Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 19
Server Version: 1.12.5
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 19
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host bridge null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-53-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.56 GiB
Name: de3lxd-107769
ID: PU5F:LZ55:EEK7:W3R7:SYR3:336J:2VRH:35H2:MTLY:6Q6L:BWBP:EM5R
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

`docker-compose -v`

```
docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
```

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hot fix

I fixed the problem by giving writer permission to everyone.

```
mkdir output
touch output/reports.db output/database.log
chmod a+rw output output/*
```

This will give the user on the host machine and the root user in the docker machine permissions, no matter who owns the files. This is just a dirty fix, because I had to hurry up. Any process could access the and edit/delete the files. It would be better If only the docker user get's writing permission, but I couldn't give writer permission to the root user on the host machine.

### Better approach

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29251160/1811501) they're using another user (www-data) in the container. After building the image they get the id of the user and replace the current file owner with this id. If you start the container as this user (www-data), the mount will copy the files with permissions and owner information, so the user can read and write to these files.

It would be a more secure way because you make sure that only the docker user can change the database/files. Because I couldn't make this work for me (seems to not work for root user with id=0), but I wanted to point out, that there is a better solution.

If you only need the data in the end after the docker stopped you might have a look at [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

Comment: no that wont fix it, I have `-rwxrwxrwx 1 1001 1001 90112 Jan  8 22:41 dev.db` and container still cant write to database.

Comment: @markokraljevic Same here.

Comment: Samoe here too.

Comment: Did you change the perms on the dir too?