# DroneCI server 0.8 unable to open database file

Tags: sqlite, docker-compose, drone.io

I'm struggling to get DroneCI up and running, using the below (sanitized) `docker-compose.yaml`.

(See link at bottom for output from `docker-compose up` executions).

```
# Docker compose file syntax:
version: '2'

services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:0.8

    ports:
      - 5124:8000
      - 5125:9000
    volumes:
      - '/var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone/:Z'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_OPEN=true
      - DRONE_HOST=http://drone.COMPANY.intra:80
      - DRONE_STASH=true
      - DRONE_STASH_GIT_USERNAME=USERNAME
      - DRONE_STASH_GIT_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
      - DRONE_STASH_CONSUMER_KEY=CONSUMER_KEY
      - DRONE_STASH_CONSUMER_RSA=/etc/bitbucket/key.pem
      - DRONE_STASH_URL=https://COMPANY_URL.intra
      - DRONE_SECRET=SECRET1
    volumes:
      - '/etc/bitbucket/key.pem:/etc/bitbucket/key.pem:Z'

  drone-agent:
    image: drone/agent:0.8

    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:Z
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER=http://drone.COMPANY.intra
      - DRONE_SECRET=SECRET1
```

*What is it I am missing/not seeing?*

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41263454/1503549), which seems eerily familiar...

However, if that's the root cause, how can I set the permissions of a database file I'm currently assuming resides in the `drone/drone:0.8` image?
(Seems strange that it'd be the container creating it though...)

There's also no mention of a database file in the official documentation, neither [here](http://readme.drone.io/admin/setup-bitbuket-server/) nor [here](http://docs.drone.io/installation/) =/.

Links:

1. Original discussion @[discourse.drone.io](https://discourse.drone.io/t/drone-v-0-8-docker-compose-unable-to-open-database-file/1833/9?u=x10an14).

   - (Was advised to try my luck here @ S/O).
2. Link to promised gist with normal (and verbose) - sanitized! - output:

   - https://gist.github.com/x10an14/d2bca6c0287a281404d2d3385f73a084#file-output-txt-L43

Comment: Does `/var/lib/drone` exist and has permissions set so drone/docker can access it and create files there?

Comment: No, it does not. That was one of the things I became uncertain of whether or not I had to ensure myself (when reading the docs). Thanks! =)

Testing it out, I see that I've got some other http2client/grpc errors depending on whether or not that host-based folder (with permissions) exist. But I'll make another question for that issue if I can't find one! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two things wrong with your docker-compose file:

1) you have the `volumes:` section twice in the config for the drone server, consolidate and put both volume mappings in the same section

2) in the drone agent config, the URL of the drone server is wrong, it shouldn't include the `http://` scheme and it's missing the port, try `DRONE_SERVER=drone-server:9000`

`docker-compose.yml`

```
# Docker compose file syntax:
version: '2'

services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:0.8

    ports:
      - 5124:8000
      - 5125:9000
    volumes:
      - '/var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone/:Z'
      - '/etc/bitbucket/key.pem:/etc/bitbucket/key.pem:Z'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_OPEN=true
      - DRONE_HOST=http://drone.COMPANY.intra:80
      - DRONE_STASH=true
      - DRONE_STASH_GIT_USERNAME=USERNAME
      - DRONE_STASH_GIT_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
      - DRONE_STASH_CONSUMER_KEY=CONSUMER_KEY
      - DRONE_STASH_CONSUMER_RSA=/etc/bitbucket/key.pem
      - DRONE_STASH_URL=https://COMPANY_URL.intra
      - DRONE_SECRET=SECRET1

  drone-agent:
    image: drone/agent:0.8

    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:Z
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER=drone-server:9000
      - DRONE_SECRET=SECRET1
```

Comment: Yup! I do believe the duplicate `volumes` was the issue here!
(My fault for following the BitBucket installation instructions without critical thought, ref [Private Key File section](http://readme.drone.io/admin/setup-bitbuket-server/)).

Maybe something for someone with edit permissions of the docs to fix? =)