# TestCafe chromium test run as part of docker build

Tags: automated-tests, chromium, e2e-testing, testcafe, docker-build

For some reason, in our CI, we need to run node tests inside docker container (including fetching dependencies, etc.). So, I am trying to have UI tests run as a part of docker build.

This is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe:1.3.3

USER root

#some packages needed for some dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache yarn python make build-base vim curl 

RUN ln -s /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh /usr/local/bin/testcafe-docker

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN yarn config set registry https://private-npm-registry --global

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

RUN yarn test:ui:ci

# "test:ui:clean": "rm -rf uitests/reports"
# "test:ui:ci-debug": "yarn test:ui:clean; testcafe-docker 'chromium --no-sandbox' uitests/tests -S -s uitests/reports/screenshots --video uitests/reports/videos -r spec,json:uitests/reports/report.json,html:uitests/reports/report.html",
# "test:ui:ci": "start-server-and-test serve http://127.0.0.1:8080 test:ui:ci-debug"
```

I get `ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.`

Also, I tried using `user` user, but it gives permission error when creating `reports` folder inside `uitests` folder before running tests.

I tried it with and without the `--no-sandbox` option, got the same issue. Also tried `chromium:headless --no-sandbox`, got the same error.

Any suggestion, please? Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
Also tried with user: `user` (avoiding permission issue by using `/tmp` folder for report) and got same issue:

```
20-Jul-2019 23:53:33    > yarn test:ui:clean; whoami; ls -sail; testcafe-docker 'chromium --no-sandbox' uitests/tests -S -s /tmp/uitests/reports/screenshots --video /tmp/uitests/reports/videos -r spec,json:/tmp/uitests/reports/report.json,html:/tmp/uitests/reports/report.html
20-Jul-2019 23:53:33    
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34    $ rm -rf /tmp/uitests/reports
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34    user
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34    total 528
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         13      4 drwxr-xr-x   10 user     user          4096 Jul 20 13:52 .
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         12      4 drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root          4096 Jul 20 13:52 ..
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         79      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            20 Jul 19 07:06 .dockerignore
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         75      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            45 Jul 19 07:06 .eslintignore
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         83      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           790 Jul 19 07:06 .eslintrc
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         78      4 drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root          4096 Jul 20 13:48 .git
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         82      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           326 Jul 20 13:48 .gitignore
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         87      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           189 Jul 19 07:06 Dockerfile
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         81      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           592 Jul 20 13:48 DockerfileUITest
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         89      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           451 Jul 19 07:06 README.md
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         90      4 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jul 19 07:06 backend
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34       4096      4 drwxr-xr-x    3 user     user          4096 Jul 20 13:53 build
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         85      4 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           959 Jul 19 07:06 build.sh
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         84      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1124 Jul 19 07:06 deploy.yaml
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         91      4 drwxr-xr-x 1348 user     user          4096 Jul 20 13:52 node_modules
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         74      4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2959 Jul 20 13:48 package.json
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         76      4 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul 19 07:06 public
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         88      4 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           742 Jul 19 07:06 runUITestsInCI.sh
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         77      4 drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root          4096 Jul 19 07:06 src
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         80      4 drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4096 Jul 19 07:06 uitests
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34         86    448 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root        454847 Jul 20 13:48 yarn.lock
20-Jul-2019 23:53:34    Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
20-Jul-2019 23:55:36    ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.
20-Jul-2019 23:55:36    
20-Jul-2019 23:55:36    Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

**Update-2:**
Tried with firefox as well and same issue: `ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.`

**Update-3:**
Sorry for the delay. Got distracted in something else. Tried both in CI and local machine and it was same behaviour. Also tried suggestion in comment `echo -e '#!/bin/sh\n/usr/bin/chromium-browser --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=9222 --headless' > /usr/local/bin/testcafe-docker` and got following output in both CI and local env.

```
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/711c6409-be9a-4e08-959e-0c994c8c5742
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.060637:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(282)] Failed to load /usr/lib/chromium/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: Error loading shared library /usr/lib/chromium/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: No such file or directory
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.064824:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(176)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.072317:WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(341)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.072782:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1220)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.135149:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(282)] Failed to load /usr/lib/chromium/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: Error loading shared library /usr/lib/chromium/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: No such file or directory
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.139203:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(176)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.143251:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1220)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.208950:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] Reinitialized the GPU process after a crash. The reported initialization time was 0 ms
02-Dec-2019 18:45:17    [1202/074517.209227:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(397)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create shared context for virtualization.
```

Comment: Could you please check whether the issue is reproducible:
- in Docker on your local machine?
- in Docker on the CI with the TestCafe image?
 
Also, you might want to replace `RUN ln -s /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh /usr/local/bin/testcafe-docker` in your Docker file with this line: `RUN echo -e '#!/bin/sh\n/usr/bin/chromium-browser --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=9222 --headless' > /usr/local/bin/testcafe-docker; chmod +x /usr/local/bin/testcafe-docker` and provide us with the Chrome output.

Comment: updated original question. Sorry for delay. Does it have vnc? possible to see a browser (non-headless) inside docker container?

Answer (score 2):

The recent 'Chromium' versions are not allow you to run them under the `root` user. Change the user from 'root' to `user` before running TestCafe tests.
Also, you need to setup permission for creating new folders. 
See the detailed explanation in [write in shared volumes docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245216/write-in-shared-volumes-docker/29251160#29251160)

```js
...
USER user
RUN yarn test:ui:ci
```

Comment: I tried with `user` as well.. but it was same.. updated original question.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a docker image without your private stuff?

Comment: Solved. My test was trying to open url: `localhost:8080`.. changing that to `127.0.0.1:8080` worked. probably some resolution issue in docker container.. but it would have been great if error message were more clear.. e.g. `couldn't reach localhost:8080`. A scope for future improvement.

Comment: Actually it was because of proxy. We use proxy to reach internet. I was adding `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy` in docker image. Probably browser in docker container was trying to reach testcafe server (running in same container) through proxy. (because it does not use 127.0.0.1/localhost?) Removing proxy setting works for now because I don't need to access internet in this test.

Comment: Adding `172.17.0.2` to `no_proxy ` worked for me. Going to add `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` to `no_proxy`.. we won't be reaching anything on internet through ip address.

Comment: still getting the same error and I'm not hitting localhost but a FQDN

Answer (score 0):

It is because of proxy. We use proxy to reach internet. I was adding `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy(127.0.0.1)` in docker image. Browser in docker container was trying to reach testcafe server (running in same container) through proxy, because it does not use `127.0.0.1/localhost` but `172.17.0.2`as testcafe server host inside container. So adding `172.17.0.2` to `no_proxy` works.