# How to modify files in wordpress docker volume?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

This is my `docker-composer.yml` for wordpress:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
      - ./all:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
   phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
     ports:
       - "8084:80"
     links:
       - db:db
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

The folder `all` contains all the files that ship from the wordpress docker image. However, they all have user/group `www-data:www-data` and the permission of the files is 644 and from folders 755, i.e. even if I add myself to the `www-data` group I have no right to modfiy or create files.

---

My research:

- I found at [write in shared volumes docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245216/write-in-shared-volumes-docker/29251160#29251160) that someone had the opposite problem, he created files and his docker image could not access it. The solution seems to be to run docker and create a file with user `www-data` -  but I don't see how I can apply this to my problem.
- I tried to add `user: "1000:1000` in the worpdress service inside `docker-composer.yml`, in hope, that all file permissions set by docker would be from my user. However, I get 1000 lines of erros of this form:

> wordpress_1   | tar: ./wp-admin: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
> wordpress_1   | tar: ./wp-admin/options-reading.php: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

A bit old of a thread but i also was looking on how to update files on a `wordpress:latest` container.
I ended using a [docker cp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/how-to-copy-files-from-host-to-docker-container) on the file i need to change. For instance :

```bash
docker cp ./functions_edited.php  6666aa5bbd76:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/functions.php
```

to edit the theme functions on the running container.

This works for me since i don't need to persists my changes when the container dies and i need just to change a single file. Maybe this is not your use case.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just to change the file permission of all files and folders from folder `all` to 777 recursively. Since this is only local development, there is no risk involved.

When I create a new file from my host it only has 644 permission, i.e. it can be read by from localhost but not edited, for that I would manually need to change the permission to 777.